# Geoserver polygon labeling Arabic numbers using SLD

Tags: python, geoserver, labeling, sld

I've used SLD to label polygon features with their parcel Ids. The problem is for Ids include '.' and '-' marks, the ordering of character is messed up. For example 39.1 changes to 139. I've checked them in Pgsql and ArcMap which show them correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>parcels</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>parcels</se:Name>

      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>2000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
             <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#7e7e7e</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.7</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <se:TextSymbolizer> 
            <se:Geometry>
              <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
            </se:Geometry>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>id_fa</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Iranian Sans</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">11</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">normal</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>0.0</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
                <se:Displacement>
                  <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
                  <se:DisplacementY>5</se:DisplacementY>
                </se:Displacement>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#523735</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="autoWrap">150</se:VendorOption>
            <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</se:VendorOption>
            <se:VendorOption name="group">yes</se:VendorOption>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>

    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I should mention that I've translated English numbers to Arabic format using python and inserted them in a new field. Is it something wrong with that process?

Comment: Does Iranian sans have a - & . character?

Comment: @IanTurton yes it includes those characters and for other labels from osm data it works properly.

Comment: do they show up correctly if you use a different font?

Comment: @IanTurton nope, but they show up correctly in Postgresql, QGIS and python.

Comment: then we need a small sample of the file to test with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was about the converting process of IDs to Arabic numbering format. I explored that there are two different Unicode types for Arabic numbers as stated [here](https://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&utf8=string-literal). In my method, all numbers should have been followed the same Unicode group such as (\xd9... or \xdb...) which I've fixed it and IDs show up properly.

```
def enToFaNumber(letter):
    charDict = {'0': '۰', '1': '۱', '2': '۲', '3': '۳', '4': '۴', '5': '۵', '6': '۶', '7': '۷', '8': '۸', '9': '۹',
                '.': '/'}
    char = charDict.get(letter)
    if char is None:
        return letter.encode('utf-8')

    return char
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this with the GeoServer `topp:States` layer, using the following SLD:

```
     <TextSymbolizer>         
        <Label>
          <ogc:Sub>
          <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_FIPS</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>23.5</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Sub>
        </Label>
        <Font>
          <CssParameter name="font-family">Iranian Sans</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-size">11</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</CssParameter>
        </Font>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#523735</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
        <VendorOption name="autoWrap">150</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="group">yes</VendorOption>
      </TextSymbolizer>
```

I get this map:

[image]

So it may be related to the python modification you are doing, if you can reproduce it with an included dataset, or with a small sample of your data feel free to open a [GeoServer bug](http://geoserver.org/issues/).

Comment: Thanks Ian the problem was about converting script and it's not a bug.